# Why is my GUI-based method running independently, but when I call it through another GUI-based class, it doesn't run?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, methods, bluej

Hey so I'm a beginner in java coding and I've been working a lot with GUI lately. I have a public class called Main Page which has two buttons: an exit button and another button that calls another GUI method "test". Main Page is able to call "exit" from another class, but not "test". Whenever I run this method individually, it works, but when I call it using Main Page, it opens the program and there's just a blank, gray screen and none of the GUI elements show up. I'm confused as to why this is happening and would appreciate any help :). The IDE I'm using is BlueJ if that helps. This is how I call my method in my program:

```
if(s.equals("Test"))
        {
            
            try
            {
                Test hp = new Test();
             }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               
           }
            
       }
```

And this is what the initial part of the method looks like:

```
import java.lang.Object;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.*;  
import java.io.*; 
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;    
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.lang.Object;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    //private JMenuBar menuBar;
    JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea q1,q2, q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10,q11,q12,q13,q14,q15,q16,q17,q18,q19,q20;
    private JTextField a1, a2, a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18,a19,a20;
    private JButton l1;
    private JButton b1, b2, b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16,b17,b18,b19,b20; 
 
    //Constructor 
    public Test() throws InterruptedException{
```

Comment: For starters, **never ignore exceptions**.

Comment: Hard to say without any real code from the `Test` class. It could be that it throws an exception, but you will never really know if you just ignore all exceptions and continue as if nothing has happend. You should at least add `e.printStackTrace();` to your catch block. And please cleanup your import statements. For example, you have three times `import java.awt.*;` - importing the package once is sufficient.

Comment: Once you've added the call to `printStackTrace()` as mentioned by @ThomasKläger, there should be more useful output as to the cause of the error. See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556). If you need further help solving the problem, create a [mre] that demonstrates it, then [edit] to add it.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about the import statements haha I was copying and pasting a lot from different locations and forgot to clean up some of that @ThomasKläger. I added the .printStackTrace(). The reason I had a try-catch component was because I use TimeUnit in the "Test" class, so it throws an InterruptedException.

Comment: So .. you have solved the problem with using `TimeUnit`?